# Insert records into collection type Oracle

Tags: oracle

I want to inserted into my collection some SQL records, but I can not. I'm a beginner. Can you help me ?
This is my tables :

```
CREATE TYPE article_type AS OBJECT (idA CHAR(10), nomA CHAR(10), prixA CHAR(10) )
CREATE TYPE facture_type AS OBJECT (idF CHAR(10), dateFact DATE) 
CREATE TYPE ens_collection_fact AS OBJECT (refFact facture_type, refArticle article_type)
CREATE TYPE collection_fact AS TABLE OF ens_collection_fact 
CREATE TYPE client_type AS OBJECT (idC NUMBER, nomC CHAR(10),adresse CHAR(10), Compose collection_fact ) 
CREATE TABLE Article OF article_type
CREATE TABLE Facture OF facture_type
CREATE TABLE Client OF client_type (PRIMARY KEY(idC)) NESTED TABLE Compose STORE AS temp
```

This is my query that I want to insert, but I have an error from the Oracle : ORA-02315

```
INSERT INTO ECOLER.CLIENT VALUES
(100, 'Jules Verne', '1', Collection_fact(Ens_collection_fact(reffact('A','2002-12-10'), ens_collection_fact(refarticle('D','E','F'))) ))
```

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

`reffact` and `refarticle` are identifiers for objects within other objects, not types; you need to refer to the actual types. You also need to supply both values for each `Ens_collection_fact` attribute for the default constructor; you can pass null if you only want one or the other:

```
INSERT INTO CLIENT VALUES
(100, 'Jules Verne', '1',
  Collection_fact(
    Ens_collection_fact(facture_type('A',date '2002-12-10'), null),
    Ens_collection_fact(null, article_type('D','E','F'))
  )
)
```

Also notice that I've added the `date` keyword so it's providing an actual date literal rather than a string, which would be converted - if you're lucky - with your session NLS settings.

This will still error because 'Jules Verne' is 11 characters and you've defined the name attribute as 10 characters/bytes, but it will work with a shorter string literal.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=56b0ce7ec37585078c0b6d2961f18934)

Comment: Thank you, your query only adds on the type facture_type but not in article_type I have that nul.

Comment: In your question you have a `Collection_fact` with two `Ens_collection_fact` elements; each of those only has one argument. So I've replicated what your question has. If you want both facture and article in one object then supply both - replace the nulls with the other object type.